# how to get the type value from xml in Mule 4

Tags: dataweave, mule4

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <order>
       <id type="integer">4258477000</id>
       <email>khaleed@mmtvbd.com</email>
       <closed-at type="dateTime" nil="true"/>
       <created-at type="dateTime">2016-10-24T21:41:51+06:00</created-at>
       <updated-at type="dateTime">2016-10-24T21:41:52+06:00</updated-at>
    <number type="integer">19</number>
    </order>
    <Notification>
      <Id>4535etrete</Id>
      <sObject xsi:type="sf:val" xmlns:sf="urn:sobject.enterprise.soap.sforce.com">
      <sf:Programs>F Type A</sf:Programs>
</sObject>
```

I want to get the value of <`sOject>` type ie  `sa:val`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all your xml is not valid. I modified it to the following to provide you a sample.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <order xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
       <id type="integer">4258477000</id>
       <email>khaleed@mmtvbd.com</email>
       <closed-at type="dateTime" nil="true"/>
       <created-at type="dateTime">2016-10-24T21:41:51+06:00</created-at>
       <updated-at type="dateTime">2016-10-24T21:41:52+06:00</updated-at>
       <number type="integer">19</number>
    <Notification>
      <Id>4535etrete</Id>
      <sObject xsi:type="sf:val" xmlns:sf="urn:sobject.enterprise.soap.sforce.com">
      <sf:Programs>F Type A</sf:Programs>
     </sObject>
    </Notification>
  </order>
```

The DW script to procure the attribute 'type' from sObject will be as follows:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
payload.order.Notification.sObject.@'type'
```